# What is the location of the Hypoglossal nerve?

Tags: neuroscience, human-anatomy, neuroanatomy, literature, cranial-nerves

I kind of know where the hypoglossal nerve is located when I look at the diagram, but I'd like to know how far is the nerve from the skin and where is the closest area to the skin before and right after it's branching?

Is there any video or schema showing the location of the Hypoglossal nerve relative to skin and not the skeleton?

From this pic. I can't really tell the closest location of being able to detect the nerve near the skin.

[image]

Comment: I found a video of a surgery on youtube where the surgeon locates both the facial nerve and the hypoglossal nerve. It is a surgery so I "warn" you before clicking the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5brqIa_KLk

Answer (score 3):

The following image of a cadaver shows the hypoglossal highlighted:

[image]

<sup>Source: [StudyBlue](https://www.studyblue.com/notes/note/n/root-of-neck/deck/4884323)</sup>

You can see the flap of skin/muscle that has been removed to get an understanding of the thickness of tissues separating the nerve from outside the body.

Additionally, here is an image showing a person receiving an operation. You can see the relative depth of the nerve fairly well:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/atlas-of-surgical-techniques-in-trauma/carotid-artery-and-internal-jugular-vein-injuries/7DB03EED13DEDD7C4ED6F46E8F528186)</sup>